# How to fix this SQL error while updating table using join?

Tags: sql, node.js

The code finds the needed data and performs the actions on it.

checktablesql1 checks if there will be stock after purchase

checktablesql2 inserts the value into a new table further other use

checktablesql3 searches for sales with the users email id

checktablesql4 updates the inventory with new stock after purchase

checktablesql5 deletes the data after purchare

My problem is that the sql syntax for checktablesql4  is wrong.

---

```
//This one works, used this to test if my logic works
let checktablesql4 = `SELECT i.Stock,i.Stock-s.NumberItems,s.idMedicineDatabase FROM inventory as i INNER JOIN sales as s ON s.idMedicineDatabase=i.idMedicineDatabase WHERE s.idMedicineDatabase IN (${result.map(r => r.idMedicineDatabase).join(',')}) AND s.customerEmail=? AND i.EmailID=?`;
//This one doesnt work, i get sql error, photo attached below
let checktablesql4 = `UPDATE inventory set i.Stock=i.Stock-s.NumberItems FROM inventory as i INNER JOIN sales as s ON s.idMedicineDatabase=i.idMedicineDatabase WHERE s.idMedicineDatabase IN (${result.map(r => r.idMedicineDatabase).join(',')}) AND s.customerEmail=? AND i.EmailID=?`;
```

### [image: Error Message]

**Full Code**

```
let checktablesql1 = `SELECT s.NumberItems,s.idMedicineDatabase,i.Stock-i.minStock-s.NumberItems as AvailableStock from sales as s inner join inventory as i ON i.idMedicineDatabase=s.idMedicineDatabase where s.CustomerEmail=? order by AvailableStock`;
let checktablesql2 = `INSERT into salehistory(idSales,idMedicineDatabase,NumberItems,CustomerEmail,SellSession,SaleDate) SELECT idSales,idMedicineDatabase,NumberItems,CustomerEmail,SellSession,SaleDate FROM sales WHERE CustomerEmail=?`;
let checktablesql3 = `SELECT * from sales where CustomerEmail=?`;
let checktablesql5 = `DELETE FROM sales where CustomerEmail=?`;

app.post('/checktable',(req, res) => {
    const EmailID1=sellEmailID1;
    const userEmailID1="abhitayshinde@gmail.com";
    db.query(checktablesql1,[EmailID1], (err, result) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("checktablesql1",result)
            if(result[0].AvailableStock>0){
                db.query(checktablesql2,[EmailID1], (err, result) => {

                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        db.query(checktablesql3,[EmailID1], (err, result) => {

                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log("checktablesql3",result)

                                //let checktablesql4 = `SELECT i.Stock,i.Stock-s.NumberItems,s.idMedicineDatabase FROM inventory as i INNER JOIN sales as s ON s.idMedicineDatabase=i.idMedicineDatabase WHERE s.idMedicineDatabase IN (${result.map(r => r.idMedicineDatabase).join(',')}) AND s.customerEmail=? AND i.EmailID=?`;
                                let checktablesql4 = `UPDATE inventory set i.Stock=i.Stock-s.NumberItems FROM inventory as i INNER JOIN sales as s ON s.idMedicineDatabase=i.idMedicineDatabase WHERE s.idMedicineDatabase IN (${result.map(r => r.idMedicineDatabase).join(',')}) AND s.customerEmail=? AND i.EmailID=?`;
                                db.query(checktablesql4,[EmailID1,userEmailID1], (err, result) => {

                                    if (err) {
                                        console.log(err);
                                    } else {
                                        console.log("checktablesql4",result)
                                        db.query(checktablesql5,[EmailID1], (err, result) => {
            
                                            if (err) {
                                                console.log(err);
                                            } else {
                                                
                                            }  
                                        })
                                    }
                                    })  
                            }  
                        })
                        
                        }

                })
            }
        }
    })




})
```

Comment: https://www.markheath.net/post/effective-debugging-with-divide-and-conquer

Comment: @jarlh i already did that, the problem is in update using join because when I use select the code is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From doesn't work in this case
Use this instead

```
let checktablesql4 = `UPDATE inventory as i INNER JOIN sales s ON i.idMedicineDatabase=s.idMedicineDatabase SET i.Stock= i.Stock-s.NumberItems WHERE s.idMedicineDatabase IN (${result.map(r => r.idMedicineDatabase).join(',')}) AND s.customerEmail=? AND i.EmailID=?`;
```